# Parsing JSON with Python Requests for Django App

Tags: python, django, json, python-requests

I'm having trouble parsing this request. It looks like this:

```
{"randomnumber": {"id":blah, "name":blah, ... }, "randomnumber22": { ... }}
```

Using python requests, I retrieve the url that returns that data, and decode it so I can try to loop through the fields. I then endup with something like:

```
{u'randomnumber': {u'id':u'blah', ... }, u'randomnumber22': { .. }}
```

And when I try to use a for-loop to stroll through the data, it complains that I need to use numbers for string indices. How can I handle this problem properly?

My simplified code:

```
import requests
network = requests.get('http://example.com')
networkoffers = network.json()
for offers in networkoffers:
    offer['name']
```

So I'm trying to access network['randomnumber']['name'], going by my initial example of the request data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating through the dict's keys, so you need to account for this in your `for` loop like this:

```
for offer in networkoffers:  # will look through keys, which are strings and not dicts
    networkoffers[offer]['name']
```

`networkoffers` is a `dict`, and `offers` (or `offer`, note the discrepancy) is a key (a `string`). `offers['name']` means nothing to Python, since offers is a string. But `networkoffers[offers]` is a dict (a value of `networkoffers`).